# GAE posting an array to the datastore with Python (One to Many)

Tags: python, angularjs, google-app-engine, webapp2

Been workining with GAE for a few months. It's my first time working with One-to-Many relationships here. Everything has been posting all well to the datastore until I started with relationships. This is the first one. Could someone please help me with this 'post' to datastore? The docs and other examples are quite confusing for now. I know I'm doing it incorrectly by `employees=r['Employees'],` I just want a simple post first. If you could plunker it even better! I am getting a BadValueError upon posting as shown;

[image]

**model.py**

```
class Project(ndb.Model):
    projectID = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    startAt = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed=True)
    endAt = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    employees = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Employees', repeated=True)

class Employees(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    role = ndb.StringProperty()
```

**handlers.py**

```
 def post(self):
    r = json.loads(self.request.body) 
    print str(r)

    g = Project(projectID=int(r['ProjectID']),  
                description=r['Description'],
                title=r['Title'],
                employees=r['Employees'],
                startAt=datetime.strptime(r['StartAt'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p'),
                endAt=datetime.strptime(r['EndAt'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p'))

    project_key = g.put()
    project_key.get()
    print project_key
```

**controller.js**

```
    $scope.employees = [
                            {
                                name:'mark',
                                role: 'dev'
                            }, 
                            {
                                name:'colin',
                                role: 'dev2'
                            }, 
                       ];
```

**UPDATE----------------------------------------------------------------------**

**json handler**

```
class commentsJsonHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
@classmethod
def route(cls):
    """
    name: index, template: /
    """
    return webapp2.Route('/comments', handler=cls, name='_commments_')


def get(self):  
    recommendations = Project.query()

    def date_handler(obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return obj.isoformat()
        else:
            raise TypeError

    self.response.out.write(json.dumps([dict(rec.to_dict(), **dict(id=rec.key.id())) for rec in recommendations], default=date_handler))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over the employees collection in your json payload and create those Employee entities first and use their keys to create the Project entity

```
def post(self):
    r = json.loads(self.request.body)
    print str(r)
    employee_keys = []
    for emp in r['Employees']:
        employee = Employees(name=emp['name'], role=emp['role'])
        employee.put()
        employee_keys.append(employee.key)


    g = Project(projectID=int(r['ProjectID']),
                description=r['Description'],
                title=r['Title'],
                employees=employee_keys,
                startAt=datetime.strptime(r['StartAt'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p'),
                endAt=datetime.strptime(r['EndAt'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p'))

    project_key = g.put()
    project_key.get()
    print project_key
```

Comment: Definitely want to accumulate you new employee entities in a list then do a ndb.put_multi() after the loop. Never** do individual put()s in a loop if you want fast response times. (** never say never)

Comment: @stevep thanks for the extra insight. Well solved @gipsy. So now my json handler is having issues dumping keys with json.dumps() when I `self.response.out.write(json.dumps([rec.to_dict() for rec in recommendations], default=date_handler))`. From `Project.query()` is where `recommendations` is coming. A `TypeError` is raised.

Comment: I have added the json handler to the question. After editing the code to be able to read `key`'s, it stops recognizing datetimeobjects

Comment: @colin_dev256 That is because your date_handler is raising the TypeError! You should actually return the object itself  if the type is not datetime.

Comment: @gipsy I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I understand what the error is about. When I try to debug, python spits out a number of my dates  pretty well until it hits that object with the `employees`.

Comment: @colin_dev256 Exactly ! That is what is happening. When Your date_handler encounters a non datetime object it throws the exception. You should return obj from your else block in your date_handler instead of throwing TypeError . i.e the date handler just handles dates and returns other objects as is.

Comment: Cool. I think we are now on the same page. However I'm not sure how to go about that. Could you please edit/update the json handler as this is this my first time working with one-to-many's. I've tried with `obj[key]` - not working. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @colin_dev256 simply replace 'raise TypeError' with 'return obj'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127186/discussion-between-colin-dev256-and-gipsy).

Comment: Figured it out. Solution was to replace `raise TypeError` with `return str(obj)`.